# Does Takenoko work as a 2 player game?

Tags: takenoko

I am wondering how well Takenoko plays with 2 players. What is the main problems only playing with 2, if any?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as the rules go the only difference is that the end of the game is triggered by one person completing 9 objective cards as opposed to 7 and 8 with 3 or 4 players respectively.

Takenoko works great as a 2 player game, there isn't much difference between the player counts. In fact, the game might be slightly less random with less people, but luck still plays a large role either way.